# writing a for loop in c

Tags: c, for-loop, compiler-errors, nested-loops, cs50

everyone! i am trying to resolve a mario problem in cs50, and when i insert a for loop like that:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int height;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 9;

    do
    {
        height = get_int("establish the height of the pyramide: ");
    }
    while (height < 1 || height > 8);
    printf("you select the height of: %i\n", height);

    for (i < height; i++)
    {
        for (j > height; j++)
        {
            printf("#");
        }
    }
}
```

i get an error like that:

> mario.c:17:12: error: relational comparison result unused
> [-Werror,-Wunused-comparison]
> for (i <= height; i++):

i've already tried declaring i inside the loop, but the resulting error is the same. what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: your for loop is syntactically incorrect. the correct syntax is `for (i=0; i<height; i++)`. If you are only going to use `i` and `j` in the loops you can declare them there `for (int i=0; i<height; i++)`

Comment: Or `for ( ; i < height; i++)`

Comment: You could do `for (; i < height; i++)` but you *can't* do `for (; j > height; j++)` because the `j` needs to be re-initialised each time.

Comment: @Gerhard yes, it will work, but make the code less readable. If you want the initial values to be declared at the top of the function, I'd rather call them `initial_i` and `initial_j`, and then in the for loop do `for(i=initial_i; ...)`

Comment: @Sembei_Norimaki: My preference would be `for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)`. Now everything is in one place. Also `height` should at least be `constant`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C the for loop is defined the following way

```
for ( expressionopt ; expressionopt ; expressionopt ) statement
for ( declaration expressionopt ; expressionopt ) statement
```

that is it has three parts. The first part either is an expression (possibly omitted) or a declaration.

So these for loops

```
for (i < height; i++)
for (j > height; j++)
```

do not satisfy the grammar. Moreover the condition in the second loop

```
j > height
```

does not make a sense.

Also try to define variables in the minimal scope where they are used.

It seems what you need is something like the following

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < height; i++)
{
    for ( int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++)
    {
        putchar( '#' );;
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

or maybe like the following

```
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    printf( "%*c", height - i, '#' );
    for (int j = 1; j < i + 1; j++)
    {
        putchar( '#' );;
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

Comment: thank you, it really worked and i got an understanding how to print the growing from 1 to n number of hashes, before i could only repeat a hard-coded number of hashes for n times!